# Toggle CSS height with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to toggle the height of a div upon clicking it, using jQuery. Here's what I'm trying:

```
$("#otherBox").click(function() {
    if($(this).css("height") == "200") {
        $(this).css("height", "300")
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("height", "200")
    }
})
```

I'm trying to make it so if the height is 200, it's set to 300, and vice versa. Why isn't this working?

Also, if there's a way to make it smoothly move between the heights (like `slideToggle`), that'd be convenient.

Comment: Change `this` to `$(this)`.

Comment: @j08691 I fixed all the `$(this)`es, and it's still not working.

Comment: **toggleClass("className")**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parseInt, because you get "200px" not 200, and you need to wrap this with jQuery

```
if(parseInt($(this).css('height')) ==200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#otherBox").click(function() {
    if($(this).height() == 200)
        $(this).height(300);
    else
        $(this).height(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of these questions. My answer is always the easily overlooked `$.toggle()` function in jQuery.

```
$("#otherBox").toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).css({height: 300});
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css({height: 200});
    },
);
```

This code runs the functions specified on click, alternating between the two functions.

(The function is easy to overlook in the documentation since it's a seldom used overload of the more standard use of `$.toggle()`.)

Comment: Ok, figures. It's been on the deprecated list for a while, but the documentation on the method hasn't said deprecated, so I've had a hunch it was going away.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css({"height":"300px"});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/TFjAY/)